# Received Memory Warning in iPad while using Camera, Crashes the app

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, camera, xamarin

I am getting **received memory warning** in my app while using camera in iPad. It crashes my app just after click on Use Photo or right after opening camera. I am using Xamarin Studio with c# to build app. I think its related to something with GC but not sure. Have tried to release memory and dispose objects but no luck.

Here is my code :

```
imagePickerController.FinishedPickingMedia += (object sender1, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e) => {
            BeginInvokeOnMainThread (delegate
                {
                    // Dismiss the image picker first to free its memory : Recieved Memory Warning
                    //imagePickerController.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true); : Not Working
                    if(imageOriginal == null)
                        imageOriginal = new UIImage();
                    imageOriginal = e.OriginalImage;
                    imageOriginal = ResizeImageToSize(imageOriginal,640,960);
                    imageData = imageOriginal.AsJPEG (.6f);
                    buffer = new byte[imageData.Length];
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));
                    string imageContents = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
                    var imageName = Guid.NewGuid () + ".jpg";
                    //if already choose an image, delete that one
                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SyncManager.Current.tagLocationRecentImageName))
                    {
                        Proxy.GetBindingClientNew().DeleteTagLocationImageAsync(SyncManager.Current.tagLocationID,SyncManager.Current.tagLocationRecentImageName);
                        Proxy.GetBindingClientNew().DeleteTagLocationImageCompleted += HandleDeleteTagLocationImageCompleted;
                    }
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
                        Proxy.GetBindingClientNew().UploadTagLocationImageAsync(imageName.ToString(),imageContents,SyncManager.Current.tagLocationTypeID);
                        Proxy.GetBindingClientNew().UploadTagLocationImageCompleted += HandleUploadTagLocationImageCompleted;
                    });

                    var documentsDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                    string jpgFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine (documentsDirectory, imageName); // hardcoded filename, overwrites each time
                    string jpgFilenameThumb = System.IO.Path.Combine (documentsDirectory, imageName + "-thumb");
                    NSError err = null;
                    if (imageData.Save (jpgFilename, false, out err))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine ("Your image saved with name " + jpgFilename);

                        imageOriginal = ResizeImageToSize(e.OriginalImage,65,65);
                        imageData = imageOriginal.AsJPEG (.6f);
                        imageData.Save (jpgFilenameThumb, false, out err);
                    }
```

Comment: have you found a solution ?

Comment: not really, but if it helps then I found that it only crashes in iPad mini not in other iPads. So I think its something with iPad mini with iOS 7. Apple launches iOs 7 with very strict memory usage instructions. You should check that out.

Comment: I am testing on an iPad mini as well. must be a ram issue. plus it's quite random.

Comment: yeah, its quite random. Try to restart iPad when you got the problem and it'll work good for a while :)